# React material-ui shorthand classNames not working?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

`"className= "mb-4"` (marginBottom) or `className= "p-10"`(padding) not working. Can you please help.

```
<div className="mb-24"></div>
```

Comment: https://material-ui.com/system/spacing/

Answer (score 0):

In React **Material-ui**, you can not write className(shorthand) for margin/padding.because react material-ui does not support mentioned shorthand classes. you can write as following:
when you want to use margin/padding property you need to import this and use.

```
import { spacing } from '@material-ui/system';
const theme = {
  spacing: 8,
}

<Box m={-2} /> // margin: -16px;
<Box m={0} /> // margin: 0px;
<Box m={0.5} /> // margin: 4px;
<Box m={2} /> // margin: 16px;
```

and also directly use:

```
<Box m="2rem" /> // margin: 2rem;
<Box mx="auto" /> // margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
<Box my="auto" /> // margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto;
```

and 
you want to use same classes like **mb-4**:
you can import css file and you define in that. because (mb-4 classes are bootstrap shorthand classes).

demo.css:

```
.mb-4{
margin-bottom:4px;
}
```

demo.js

```
import 'demo.css';
<div className="mb-4">
```

and also you refer this document: **[material-ui.com/system/spacing](https://material-ui.com/system/spacing)**